# function "x" not defined in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

hi i am new to angularjs and i have been trying to do a table but for some reason it dose not work for me
and even the example from w3schoos dose not work for me but it works on their site

here is a link to their code : https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_tables_simple

and this is the error i get when i run it on vs on a page named index.html :index.html:10: function "x" not defined

and this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ prodcut.Price }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.products = response.data.products;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the error : panic: template: index.html:10: function "product" not defined

i send to it a json file that looks like this :

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "שוקו",
            "Price": "20",
            "Quantity": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "חלב",
            "Price": "30",
            "Quantity": 20
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "מילקי",
            "Price": "40",
            "Quantity": 30
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "קפה",
            "Price": "50",
            "Quantity": 60
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "שוקולד",
            "Price": "40",
            "Quantity": 50
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "קולה",
            "Price": "40",
            "Quantity": 50
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "טרופית",
            "Price": "5",
            "Quantity": 100
        }
    ],
    "title": "מוצרים"
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your HTML - prodcut.Price instead of product. Is that the code you are actually running?

Comment: what do you mean by if is that the code i am running?

Comment: i am using go with the gin gonic library for the back end and i can send it if its needed but i dont think thats whats not making it work

Comment: i tried more simple code as well and it dosent let me use any function at all the code here https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_bind dosent work for me as well as i try to run it i again get the error : :8: function "name" not defined

Comment: the issue is with your async api call. The products are undefined in the beginning and html template is trying to access it before its get updated by api call response. Later api call response is filling the products for you. Initialise the products array with empty array

Comment: he is trying to make api call and populate that data, so here async concept comes about which he might not aware of. If you waana try simple thing then dont make api call and just assign the products object

Comment: @Shay Hershko - sometimes people post code which is not exactly the same as the code they are actually running. Hence the question. If you have that typo in your code, you will definitely get that error. However, even when you fix it, there is the issue which others have explained. Hope you get everything working. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
product.Price
```

with

```
products.Price
```

Comment: you mean like this <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{ products.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ products.Price }}</td>
  </tr>
</table> ?

Comment: from what i am seeing after testing its like he dosnet know how to use expressions as it dosent even work with the most simple and basic example like this one https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_bind

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your async api call. The products are undefined in the beginning and html template is trying to access it before its get updated by api call response.

Initialise the products array with empty array

Change your code here

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.products = []; // added this
      $http.get("http://localhost:8080/")
        .then(function (response) {$scope.products = response.data.products;});
    });
</script>
```

here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/technotech/pen/pogXvBp) link i create for you. Please note i am using a dummy api call for demo.

if you want to try with simple object then remove api call and assign the object you want. like this

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.products =  [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "שוקו",
            "Price": "20",
            "Quantity": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "חלב",
            "Price": "30",
            "Quantity": 20
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "מילקי",
            "Price": "40",
            "Quantity": 30
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "קפה",
            "Price": "50",
            "Quantity": 60
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "שוקולד",
            "Price": "40",
            "Quantity": 50
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "קולה",
            "Price": "40",
            "Quantity": 50
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "טרופית",
            "Price": "5",
            "Quantity": 100
        }
    ]

     
    });
</script>
```

also correct the typo

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.Price }}</td> // it was prodcut.
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it still says that product is not defined ... can it be a problem with the server or how i run it ?

Comment: Yes that might be. Print the server response in console and check it out if it giving you expected response or not ?

Comment: you also have a typo . correct that one. i guess thats what it causing you error

Comment: i have no idea what is the problem at all even simple examples are not working  for me

Comment: i can send my server code if its help i use go with gin gonic library if it helps

Comment: and your fix dose work it shows the html and the data

Comment: @ShayHershko try to attach screenshot of exact error, that helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the product is undefined is because you are not casting out the value or the data that you are getting back into an array or a JSON format for ng-repeat to read.

change the following:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/")
    .then(function (response) {$scope.products = response.data.products;});
});
</script>
```

To the following

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/")
    .then(function (response)
   {
     $scope.products = response.products;});
    //log the input data in console to see if you actually are receiving data.
      console.log(response);
});
</script>
```

And then you can call the defined values in your table like you did before:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td>{{ product.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ prodcut.Price }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```